# Easily converting List of lists to numpy Multidim array for big data

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, bigdata

Let's say I have '3 deep' list of lists

```
len(list) --> 500
len(list[0]) --> 25
len(list[0][0]) --> 100
```

and I wanted to convert into a numpy array with the shape of (500, 25, 100). What would be the most efficient way of going about this computationally? assuming the list is very very large.

Comment: `np.asarray()`?

Answer (score 0):

Your list:

```
l = [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]],[[9,10],[11,12]]]
```

Your numpy array:

```
arr = np.array(l)
#array([[[ 1,  2],
#        [ 3,  4]],
#
#      [[ 5,  6],
#       [ 7,  8]],
#
#       [[ 9, 10],
#        [11, 12]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to convert it and afterwards want to run a loop over its indices:

```
l=[[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]],[[9,10],[11,12]]]
# convert
a=np.asarray(l)
# loop
for (ix,iy,iz),val in np.ndenumerate(a):
    print(ix, iy, iz, a[ix,iy,iz])
```

gives

```
0 0 0 1
0 0 1 2
0 1 0 3
0 1 1 4
1 0 0 5
1 0 1 6
1 1 0 7
1 1 1 8
2 0 0 9
2 0 1 10
2 1 0 11
2 1 1 12
```